# passing jquery data to WebMethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I know we already have many posts about this topic, but I just cannot figure out how to pass the data to WebMethod! All I need is to pass one string data to my WebMethod, but do I need to use list data type?

.js

```
function buttonClicked () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "Chat.aspx/send",
    data: "{'text':'" + $("#writeBox").val() +  "'}",
    success: function () {
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
}
```

.aspx (updated with full codes)// I commented out the part that incurs error

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
void send (string text) {
    string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["id"].ToString();
    string queryString = "INSERT INTO Log (ID, Text, Date) Values (" + id + ", " + text + ", GETDATE())";
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=ChatV1;Integrated Security=True");
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, con);
    using (con)
    {
       con.Open();
       //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: you do right , what is your problem ?!

Comment: I get 500 internet server error on chrome javascript console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void send (string text) {
    string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["id"].ToString();
    string queryString = "INSERT INTO Log (ID, Text, Date) Values (" + id + ", " + text + ", GETDATE())";
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=ChatV1;Integrated Security=True");
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(queryString, con);        
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
}
```

Comment: I cannot use static method because I need to use Request.Cookies collection to retrieve my cookie. I found out that I cannot use the collection with static method:(

Comment: So change you strategy for calling an ajax request. Use the PHP style for calling an ajax request(I mean use an other web page and call it by your ajax request,not a web method)

Comment: @SiYoungKim Did you try HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies to access cookies collection in static method?

Comment: @AliForoughi Thanks to JQone, I could put it static and now it seems to work! except when I include cmd.ExecuteNonQuery in my webmethod.

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery!!? more details needed dude

Comment: @AliForoughi With the parameter received, my WebMethod attempts to write the parameter on my database. It seems that connection to the database is fine, but the executing query is not working. I will update my post to show you the details.

Comment: Thanks, Ali. I fixed some sql statements and it seems to work now. The id string i am using is for random ideas:D